# Updating on the same MySQL table the row when the values of columns are equals

Tags: mysql

I need updating on the same MySQL table the row when the values of columns **xID** and **ID** are equals.

This is one example:

```
mysql> SELECT
    Euro,
    ALMACEN,
    Imagen,
    xID,
    ID
FROM
    `tbl_g`
WHERE
    xID IN (2025)
OR ID IN (2025);
+--------+----------+--------+------+------+
| Euro   | ALMACEN  | Imagen | xID  | ID   |
+--------+----------+--------+------+------+
| 7742,8 | ARGUALAS | NULL   | NULL | 2025 |
| NULL   | EMPALME  |        | 2025 | 4441 |
+--------+----------+--------+------+------+
2 rows in set
```

I have tried this SQL Update query without success, because the row with **xID** number 2025 not update with values of row with **ID** 2025 :

```
mysql> UPDATE `tbl_g` kkk,
 `tbl_g` jjj
SET kkk.Euro = jjj.Euro
WHERE
    kkk.ID = jjj.xID
AND kkk.xID IS NOT NULL;

Query OK, 0 rows affected
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

How to do resolve this?

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance for any help, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the table using a **`JOIN`** (self Join) and use a **`WHERE`** clause to check the column `Euro` is null.

**Query**

```
update `tbl_g` as `t1`
join `tbl_g` as `t2`
on `t1`.`xID` = `t2`.`ID`
set `t1`.`Euro` = `t2`.`Euro`
where `t1`.`Euro` is null;
```

**Note:** There is a chance for multiple rows which satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 0):

You need a self join for example

```
drop table if exists t;

create table t(Euro  decimal(10,2) , ALMACEN  varchar(20), Imagen int, xID  int, ID  int);
insert into t values
( 7742.80 , 'ARGUALAS' , NULL   , NULL , 2025),
( NULL    , 'EMPALME'  , null   , 2025 , 4441);

update t t1 join t t2 on t2.xid = t1.id
    set t2.euro = t1.euro;

select * from t;

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from t;
+---------+----------+--------+------+------+
| Euro    | ALMACEN  | Imagen | xID  | ID   |
+---------+----------+--------+------+------+
| 7742.80 | ARGUALAS |   NULL | NULL | 2025 |
| 7742.80 | EMPALME  |   NULL | 2025 | 4441 |
+---------+----------+--------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```